# Android Studio Exception in plugin Android Support 3.1.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.1

I try to create the Navigation Drawer Activity in Android Studio and when I'm opening the xml file activity_pass_menu_drawer.xml it only shows "Waiting for build to finish" although the build is already finished and shows and IDE fatal Error null java.lang.NullPointerException

```
null java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.getRenderResult(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:602)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenViewBase.getResult(ScreenViewBase.java:109)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.ScreenView.getResult(ScreenView.java:30)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.menu.NavigationViewSceneView.getPreferredSize(NavigationViewSceneView.java:64)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.SceneView.getPreferredSize(SceneView.java:95)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.createSceneViewsForMenu(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:265)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.doCreateSceneView(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:234)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.createSceneView(SceneManager.java:73)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.scene.SceneManager.<init>(SceneManager.java:66)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.<init>(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:157)
at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.surface.NlDesignSurface.createSceneManager(NlDesignSurface.java:145)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.surface.DesignSurface.setModel(DesignSurface.java:281)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.initNeleModelOnEventDispatchThread(NlEditorPanel.java:143)
at com.android.tools.idea.common.editor.NlEditorPanel.lambda$null$4(NlEditorPanel.java:139)
at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.lambda$smartInvokeLater$7(DumbServiceImpl.java:366)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$2.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:315)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:424)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:407)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

How do I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
        android:title="Travel Tips" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:title="Maps" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
        android:title="Game" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
        android:title="History" />
</group>

<item android:title="Misc">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:title="Feedback" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:title="Manual" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAvvU.jpg)

here is my build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.tocz.buzprototype2"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: close this layout tab then use rebuild from menu. if no success restart (exit and reopen) android studio.

Comment: still not working

Comment: when you see "IDE fatal Error" you may need to exit android studio and then open it.

Comment: still on error
sorry for not replying fast

Comment: can you send your gradle and also layout code it may have some problems

Comment: I edited my post I will also show the screenshot

Comment: did you try "clear caches and restart" from file menu?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using a potato computer that's why it takes time to reply

Comment: still IDE error

Comment: create a new xml menu file with different name from this file copy content of this file to that file then close this file and see when you open that new file what happens if error is solved you can delete this old file

Comment: try removing this `tools:showIn="navigation_view"` may solve the error

Comment: also you can ignore the error and continue your work with the project it is IDE error and could have no effect in your apk. when you close the file there is no error.

Comment: try removing this `tools:showIn="navigation_view"` may solve the error. `tools` namespaces have no effect in compiled apk they are only for IDE and layout show in IDE

Comment: Thank you for the answers
I'll definitely try it